# MINTEMP error after crash

Tags: reprap, hotend, thermistor

I just got my HICTOP Prusa i3 Aluminium frame printer and finished putting it together. After setting it to preheat, I realized the bed was not level - I adjusted it and accidentally caused the head to crash into the bed.

It sounded like something popped, and the printer restarted. It is now showing a `MINTEMP` error message, and both bed and hotend temperatures read 0°C.

The only visible damage is that a thin layer came off the printbed - After testing with a multimeter, I realized that the metal under this layer is connected to power. As both the bed and hotend were heating, I believe I may have caused a short.

Replacing the thermistor on the hotend with a spare did not solve the issue. I tested the thermistor on the printbed with a multimeter, and it seems to be working correctly (resistance value around ~200 kΩ at room temperature).

Which leads me to believe that I may have damaged the control board. What do I do?

Note: This is not a firmware problem as the printer was getting correct temperature readings before that. Also, I have a second extruder thermistor port that is unused. If I did damage my board, could I edit `pins.h` and `configuration.h` to use this port instead, and completely disconnect the heated printbed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After replacing the control board, it now prints flawlessly. Apparently,I really did damage the control board...

Comment: Were you able to determine what failed on the controller board?